# Spotify Flat Frame

Tags: frame, spotify, look-and-feel, items

I'd like to know how this is made:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wEC9.png

I'll explain me better.
I'd like to create programs with this type of frame but I can't understand how to do that. I tried to use Java and Photoshop to create my own frame but I think this is not the best way to do it, nor the most efficient. It would be better if buttons and other items were actually real items, not just images that change at mouseOvering or mouseOuting.

I'd also like to know what are the best languages to do so.

Hoping to have clearly explained my question, I thank you all in advance!

Comment: This might be for an old Spotify client: http://www.quora.com/What-is-the-technology-behind-the-Spotify-desktop-app Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/662121/what-language-or-technology-was-used-to-develop-the-spotify-desktop-application

Comment: @chelmertz Finally a well-explained post about the Spotify technology! Thank you!