# Software and Language differences between Web Development and Desktop Applications

Tags: programming-languages, desktop-application, software-design

So I have decided that I want to create an application that is accessible offline. I have experience creating websites using html5, css3, and javascript. I researched some of the differences but can not get a straight answer.

My question is :

What software and languages are important/crucial to know and use when building a desktop application that can be used offline but also uses online tools?

For example, Spotify. Do HTML, CSS, and javascript still get used? Does the code still get written in atom? or does everything change?

Comment: No need to post a question for this, already a lot of material related to this is present online. Ask questions which are critical and require help from community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It varies. Many desktop applications use programming languages like Java, C++, Python or C# and some desktop UI framework (read: not HTML and CSS). But other applications use [Electron](https://electronjs.org/) (or a similar approach), which allows you to write desktop applications in JavaScript, HTML and CSS.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26735516/41071), the Spotify desktop app is (or at least used to be) written both in C++ (for the "core" parts) and in JavaScript, HTML and CSS (for the UI).

The other desktop app you mentioned, Atom, is actually where Electron originated.

As for which editor is used, again, it varies. Atom can be used to write programs in many languages (including those used commonly in desktop applications). Though most people use another code editor (like Visual Studio Code or Vim) or an IDE (like Visual Studio, IntelliJ or Eclipse).

Comment: Great answer it really helped. But to clarify one thing, to do software visual design, like colors, div sizes etc.,  for desktop applications (non-online) we still use html and css, or are there other languages (c#, java, c++) that have those capabilities?